# Veil of death: no escape for a Phoenix?

Tags: harry-potter, phoenix

We know that going through the veil of death results in instant death, we also know that **when they die, phoenixes burst into flames and are reborn from their ashes.**

**But there's the thing:** the veil of death doesn't only claim the life but also the body itself, **that would mean no ashes to be reborn from**. I ask then, what would happen if a Phoenix were to fly straight into the veil of death?

Comment: Not interesting exactly, no (and it may be a duplicate?), because it smacks of knowingly asking an unanswerable question. I hope I'm wrong. Anyway, if you read *FBAWTFT* you'll see that Phoenixes *do* eventually die -- they are not immortal. They just live very long lives. As to ashes, how do you know what happens behind the veil? Maybe there would be ashes and Fawkes would live on in a different plane of existence. Or maybe he would just die and be gone forever. I think it would have to be one of the two. It's not named the veil of death, AFAIK. Isn't it just The Veil? If so, huge difference.

Comment: Yes, I knew they eventually die.the probel is for instance we don't know if when natural death finally comes for a phoenix the is a combustion.In other words could a phoenix die without burbing? I I'm not mistaken,Rowling said the veil was a physical manifestation of the frontiere between life and death, so calling it the veil of death wouldn't be far fetched...

Comment: You are right -- we *don't* know how natural death comes to a Phoenix and it's why I say this is a knowingly unanswerable question. I feel a VTC is appropriate. As to JKR saying something, paraphrasing isn't good enough -- for a JKR quote, I would personally like to see the quote fully sourced with a link (not to the HP Wikia, but a direct source) and the quote provided in the answer. It is called The Veil in the books (just as Mandrakes are called Mandrakes, not Mandragora, in the books). While YMMV, I prefer sticking to canon terms.

Comment: Ok.Sorry about the wrong spelling, being an english to french translator can mess with your head when you do it all day long...

Comment: Please don't feel the need to apologize about Mandragora! I would never admonish *anyone* for making a simple translation error -- that happens. I'm really sorry if I was rude to you -- that was not my intention. Sometimes when I'm making a point I think is important I can be overly formal and that often reads as brusque or authoritarian. So, again, my apologies to you if that's what happened here. I just wanted to make the point that I think sticking to canon terms lessens the chance for confusion for other users. :)

Comment: No it's alright, I don't mind formality, I can be quite formal using the right term is important to get the right anwswer, after all "a problem well defined is a problem half solved". It's just that the"drake" in mandrake  makes me think about dragons and I think you'll agree with me nothing could be further from a dragon than a mandrake. Anyway It would seem this question can't be answered...I swear to Merlin JKk'd better release that HP encyclopedia already. I want MOOAAR!!!

Comment: The phoenix enters limbo :(

Comment: "We don't know" is not an opinion. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/are-questions-without-enough-data-unanswerable https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/should-all-questions-without-explicit-canon-answers-be-closed https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11273/what-do-we-do-with-this-question-that-doesnt-have-a-current-answer https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11329/are-answers-that-state-we-dont-know-acceptable

Comment: Reopened in accordance with the policies linked above; cf [What would happen if a Ghost were to walk through the Veil in the Death Chamber?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17439/31394)

Answer (score 1):

### The Phoenix would be truly dead.

Reading through J.K. Rowling's statements on the veil, one sentence that stuck out to me was this:

> It's the divide between life and death. I tried to do a nod to that in the Tale of Three Brothers - she was separate from them as though through a veil. **You can't go back if you pass through that veil, you cannot come back.** Or you can't come back in any form that will make either person happy anyway.
>   <sub>[Vault 27 entry number two](https://web.archive.org/web/20120203024629/http://harryahistory.com:80/2008/09/more-about-that-veil.html)</sub>

It seems to me that, at least from this quote, there would be no escape for any living ([or non-living](/q/21725/109642)) entity, including a phoenix; retrieving the ashes from within the Veil would be like retrieving a human's body.

One important thing to note is that although not directly stated, the fact that phoenixes live “to an immense age” would seem to mean that they do eventually die.

> The phoenix lives to an immense age as it can regenerate, bursting into flames when its body begins to fail and rising again from the ashes as a chick.
>   <sub>Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them</sub>