# If ghosts are bound to the Earth for eternity, what happens if the world ends?

Tags: harry-potter

If ghosts are bound to the Earth for eternity, what happens if the world ends? Would they be floating around in the atmosphere?

Comment: Define the End of the World. The Sun expanding in five billion years and swallowing the Earth?? Probably migrate to another planet with the rest of humanity/wizardkind. Humanity dying out?? Well, learn to talk to the cockroaches I suppose, or whatever else comes after us.

Comment: Are they actually bound for eternity? I looked for some info but the only thing I could find was some completely unsourced claims in the Harry Potter wiki (which anyone can edit) mentioned at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9992/could-ghosts-in-harry-potter-move-on ...if no one can find a source in J.K. Rowling's writings for this idea, then your question wouldn't be answerable with canon sources.

Comment: I've just read and its on the harry potter wikia that they cannot move on and choose to go to earth from limbo as a ghost so I assumed they be here forever @Hypnosifl

Comment: This should be reopened, as our **policy is not to close questions without a canon answer**. See: [Should all questions without explicit canon answers be closed?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3017/33591)

Answer (score 2):

The Harry Potter universe has no end of times predictions nor does it ever speculate on that. So its safe to assume this has no answer other then pure speculation.