# Why did Moaning Myrtle choose to become a ghost?

Tags: harry-potter, ghost, basilisk

Moaning Myrtle was a ghost in Harry Potter. She is a minor character, but I would have to say that she is relevant to the series.

Her death was quite tragic. She was bullied by Olive Hornby about her glasses and retreated to the bathroom, where she died after staring in the eyes of a basilisk.

According to another ghost, Nearly Headless Nick, he says that wizards can choose to live as a ghost, but very few choose this path.

Now, let's get to the point of my question: Why did Moaning Myrtle choose to become a ghost? She didn't seem happy in the girl's bathroom, so why didn't she just move on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could ghosts in Harry Potter move on?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9992/could-ghosts-in-harry-potter-move-on), specifically [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16882/98028) which tackles Myrtle's will to stay and haunt her bully.